# Extracting numbers between two string patterns

Tags: shell-script, awk, scripting, numeric-data

I have a file with following type of expression in every line "Age=22 years and Height=6 feet", I want to extract Age and height numbers only.

I have tried

```
grep -oP  '(?<=Age=)[^years]+' $f | awk '{ printf "%d \n",$1; }
```

and get age correctly. How can I get both Age and height. When I try nested pattern match i get height only.

This is the pattern I've tried

```
grep -oP  '(?<=Age=)[^years]+.+(?<=Height=)[^feet]+' $f | awk '{ printf "%d \n",$1; }
```

Comment: Are the numbers always represented as positive integers? "Number" can mean anything like 2.3, 0x45, -1.3e30.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not doing what you think it does, it works only by accident:

```
[^years]+
```

It means, match **any character *except*** `y`, `e`, `a`, `r` and `s` at least once.

Also, instead of [Look-behind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assertion, I would use [keep-out](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html). It has the benefit that it can be of variable length, then you can easily match both `Age` and `Height`.

```
(Age|Height)=\K
```

Then, instead of making a negative match, use a positive one, matching only numbers:

```
grep -Po '(Age|Height)=\K\d+'
```

--

```
$ echo "Age=22 and Height=6" | grep -Po '(Age|Height)=\K\d+'
22
6
```

Comment: Thanks, how can i print output like this 22 6 in a row

Comment: you could  simply pipe to `xargs` --> `... | xargs`

Answer (score 2):

```
$ echo 'Age=22 years and Height=6 feet' | awk -F'[= ]' '{print $2, $6}'
22 6
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have a file with following type of expression in **every line** "Age=22 years and Height=6 feet"

With `sed` that has the `-E` option.

```bsh
sed -E 's/[^[:digit:]]+/ /g;s/^ //' <<< "Age=22 years and Height=6 feet"
```

Or if it is a file point `sed` to it.

```bsh
sed -E 's/[^[:digit:]]+/ /g;s/^ //' file.txt
```

To add both *Age* and *Height* to the pattern.

```bsh
sed -E 's/^Age=([[:digit:]][^ ]*).*Height=([[:digit:]][^ ]*).*/\1 \2/' file.txt
```

Comment: You don't need `-E` for your first example, just use `*` instead of `+`. You only need it to avoid escaping the parentheses in your last example (but it will work fine without the `-E` if you use `\(` and `\)`).  You also don't need the `g` modifier when you're anchoring a regex to the beginning of the line (`^`) since that will never match more than once.

Comment: @terdon, thank you for that wonderful comment, updated accordingly.